best way to create a "String" sql query with multiple parameter values at runtime?
I need to create a SQL query which I further need to pass it as a request body in REST API. I am struggling to find a best way to create this sql as a string
What i have so far is via the StringBuilder
        stringBuilder.append("SELECT * FROM employee "
                             + "WHERE employeeId = 'A' and employeeName IN "
                             + "('ABC', 'PQR', 'ZYZ')"
                             + " and active = 'ACTIVE' and DEPARTMENTID in ('")
                     .append(params.getDepartmentIdList)
                     .append("'")
                     .append(" and deactivate = false")
                     .append(" and triggerId = '")
                     .append(params.gettriggerId())
                     .append("'");

        return stringBuilder.toString();

The output that I get is very much what I am looking for except for the departmentId, the departmentIdList gets populated as
('[ABC, BWP, DAS, DAD]' instead of 'ABC', 'BWP', 'DAS', 'DAD'


Notice is [] in the DEPARTMENTID values
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeId = 'A' and employeeName IN ('ABC', 'PQR', 'ZYZ') and active = 'ACTIVE' and DEPARTMENTID in ('[ABC, BWP, DAS, DAD]' and deactivate = false and triggerId = '123456'

any suggestions or any other way I could achieve this?

define "best way"? (easier to read, faster, security, ...) - also helpful to know the types of involved variables - anyway, no need to use StringBuilder at all, just normal concatenation using +

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I did mention, I further need to pass it as a request body in REST API

if the question is "how to convert a list of strings into a comma separated string", I would suggest String.join(",", params.getDepartmentIdList) or similar

I was so lost in the problem, I wasn't asking myself the right question. actually, append(String.join("','",params.getDepartmentIdList) did the trick. if you want post that as an answer I will accept.

Why are you putting SQL in the body of an HTTP request? Why is the API seemingly leaking details of what its storage mechanism is?

Just for readability, I would separate the query and prepare the data beforehand.
private final static QUERY = """
  SELECT * FROM employee 
  WHERE employeeId = %s 
  AND employeeName IN '%s'
  AND active = %s 
  AND DEPARTMENTID in '%s'
  AND deactivate = %s
  AND triggerId = %s
""";

var active = "ACTIVE";
var deactivate = "false";
var employeeNames = String.join(",", List.of('ABC', 'PQR', 'ZYZ'));  
var departmentIds = String.join(",", params.getDepartmentIdList());
var triggerId = params.getTriggerId();
var queryBody = String.format(QUERY, employeeId, 
                                     employeeNames, 
                                     active, 
                                     depeartmentIds, 
                                     deactivate, 
                                     triggerId);


Two hints: you can also use ".formated([arguments])" applied to query. And while I typically like the inbuilt formating options the more arguments you want to replace the more difficult to map argument to where it goes, so I'd rather handcraft something like "SELECT ... WHERE active =$ACTIVITYLEVEL$ and DEPATMENTID in '%DEPIDS%'" and then go 'query.replace("%ACTIVITYLEVEL%, "ACTIVE").replace("%DEPIDS%", "(4,5)")' and the like.

"readability" is probably opinion-based... and maintainability should also be considered. IMO using a formatter in this case doesn't make it better than usual concatenation, also constants would be better included directly. But consistency is important too: regarding letter cases like in and and DEPARTMENTID, compared to the rest; line separation/one attribute per line, ...

Yes, it is opinion based. Just a suggestion. In my perspective it is much easier to understand what the query is intended to do when it is written in a straightforward manner, rather then following all the append functions. Regarding the naming, I used the author's query as is. Ofc better to have some consistency.
